# Pythonic code to convert 3 digit number into all possible letter combinations

Tags: python

Given a dictionary where 1:a , 2:b ... 26:z. I need to find all the possible letter combinations that can be formed from the three digits.

Either each digit should translate to a letter individually or you can combine adjacent digits to check for a letter. You can't change the order of the digits. For example -

121 translates to aba, au, la;

151 translates to aea, oa;

101 translates to ja;

I was able to get this working but I feel my code is not very "pythonic". I am trying to figure out a more efficient & python-like solution for this problem.

```
# creating the dict that has keys as digits and values as letters
root_dict = {}
for num in range(0,26):
    root_dict[str(num+1)] = string.ascii_lowercase[num]

# asking user for a three digit number
sequence_to_convert = raw_input('Enter three digit number \n')

# storing all possible permutations from the three digit number
first_permutation = sequence_to_convert[0]
second_permutation = sequence_to_convert[1]
third_permutation = sequence_to_convert[2]
fourth_permutation = sequence_to_convert[0]+sequence_to_convert[1]
fifth_permutation = sequence_to_convert[1]+sequence_to_convert[2]

# checking if the permutations exist in the dict, if so print corresponding letters
if first_permutation in root_dict and second_permutation in root_dict and third_permutation in root_dict:
    print root_dict[first_permutation]+root_dict[second_permutation]+root_dict[third_permutation]
if first_permutation in root_dict and fifth_permutation in root_dict:
    print root_dict[first_permutation]+root_dict[fifth_permutation]
if fourth_permutation in root_dict and third_permutation in root_dict:
    print root_dict[fourth_permutation]+root_dict[third_permutation]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [Python 2 is going to be no longer supported in less than a year](https://pythonclock.org/). If you are starting to learn Python now, learn Python 3. In your code the only differences are that `print` is a function now and no longer an expression (so you need `()`) and that `raw_input` was renamed `input` (and the Python 2 `input` basically no longer exists).

Your building of the root dictionary can be simplified a bit using a dictionary comprehension:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

num_to_letter = {str(i): c for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}
```

For the first three different permutations you can use tuple unpacking:

```
first, second, third = sequence_to_convert
```

Note that you are currently not validating if the user entered a valid string. The minimum you probably want is this:

```
from string import digits
digits = set(digits)

sequence_to_convert = input('Enter three digit number \n')
if len(sequence_to_convert) != 3:
    raise ValueError("Entered sequence not the right length (3)")
if not all(x in digits for x in sequence_to_convert):
    raise ValueError("Invalid characters in input (only digits allowed)")
```

(A previous version of this answer used `str.isdigit`, but that unfortunately returns true for digitlike strings such as `"¹"`...)

Your testing and printing can also be made a bit easier by putting the possible permutations into a list and iterating over it:

```
permutations = [(first, second, third), (first, fifth), (fourth, third)]
for permutation in permutations:
    if all(x in num_to_letter for x in permutation):
        print("".join(map(num_to_letter.get, permutation)))
```

However, in the end you would probably want to make this more extendable (especially to strings longer than three). For that you would need a way to get all possible one or two letter combinations, and that is hard. It is probably doable with an algorithm similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134039/4042267), but it might be worth it to ask a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) about this.

Comment: There is a `pairwise` generator in the [Itertools recipes.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @AustinHastings: I'm aware. But here you would need all partitions of a string into groups of one *or* two characters, not just the current and the following character.

Comment: `itertools.chain(a_string, pairwise(a_string))`

Comment: @AustinHastings: While this does work for the example with three characters (and so might be worth it to put it into an answer), it fails for more characters. For `1234`, it is missing e.g. `12,3,4`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was focused on pairing, and neglecting the "whole word" thing.

Comment: @AustinHastings: It does, however, give you all possible building blocks of the permutations, but building the permutations from it is the real work...

Comment: Thanks a ton guys! This has ben a huge help :) I see the errors in my ways and will work on improving !!

Comment: thanks again @Graipher this is so great, I was reviewing your solution again today to understand the thought process. It is so fundamentally different than I am processing code in my head. Are there any practice questions or material you can recommend that will help me develop similar skills? I suspect it will come with MORE practice but wondering if the right study/practice material can help get me there more quickly !